# Reinstalling glassfish into the directory of previous installation?

Tags: java, glassfish

I am new to Glassfish and I have some minor problem that I don't know how to fix. I unistalled Glassfish 2.1.1 from a directory and now I can't install it into the same directory path. I unistalled using unistall.exe, deleted all the files that were left behind and when I try to install it again, I get this message:

Existing installation has been detected in this directory. Please select another directory or uninstall existing installation before proceeding. If you choose to continue without uninstalling previous installation, installation might fail.

I checked the product registry and couldn't find any trace of the glassfish. Anyone knows what might be the problem and how to fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: check regedit to see registry entries

Answer (score 0):

Check the system variables, sometimes these servers make changes on your system variables, like path and so on

Comment: Yes, I had removed GLASSFISH_HOME, but I might have it it the PATH. I'll check it as soon as I get to my work station. Thank you, Sir.